# Keyboard shortcuts and action listeners

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, actionlistener

Wondering how to link a keyboard key to a JButton in netbeans, Downloaded KeyEventDemo program from oracle that lets you press a key and it tells you the keycode, Now im wondering how to implement that, working on a calculator project and I already have the ability to click on any button and have it either <kbd>+</kbd>,<kbd>-</kbd>,<kbd>/</kbd>,<kbd>*</kbd> or <kbd>enter</kbd> so now I am wondering how to link the 2 together, essentially I'm trying to figure out how to check which key is being pressed in a method, and then run a method depending on what they pressed! thanks for any info!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Basically you bind a KeyStroke to an Action. The tutorial also has a section on How to Use Actions.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was looking for, would upvote you if I had enough rep!